# Esri JavaScript API ApplyEdits update not working

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, update

When I attempt to applyEdits as an update to my application I receive the following errors:
[image: Error message that I receive.]
I uploaded my most recent revision on Github at: https://github.com/csergent45/streetSigns/tree/119dc2ec277a347c066f92fa13e0ca76f182fb8f

My code is is in app/main.js

You can download the app and run it; don't allow for geolocation and then click on a red point; this will open the sign editing form; you can then modify it, click update and then an error will occur in the console where applyEdits is on line 723 in the app.

Comment: it'd be substantially more convenient to help you troubleshoot your problem if you took the time to write/share a simplified repro case.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the ESRI CDN source looks like it has a broken build. For instance, you cannot pan or zoom on the map right now whereas yesterday you could. I would wait until later in the day to see if their fix doesn't take care of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your objectid value type from string to number.

your request is here :

```
updates:[{"attributes":{"objectId":"43532","mutcd":"D3-1   (Street sign)  -  Street Name & Parking Signs","installed":null,"signId":"5912","facing":"N","visibility":"Good","condition":"Good","supportId":"3680","text":" ","color1":"","delineator":"None","illum":"None","offset":"","mountht":"","backing":"Aluminum","width":"","height":"","txtSize":"","numSize":"","comments":" ","twoSided":"Y","attachType":"","attachNum":"","attachLoc":"Main pole","siteObs":"Clear","signShape":"","color2":""}}]
```

and correct request should be like this

```
updates:[{"attributes":{"objectId":43532,"mutcd":"D3-1   (Street sign)  -  Street Name & Parking Signs","installed":null,"signId":"5912","facing":"N","visibility":"Good","condition_":"Good","supportId":"3680","text":" ","color1":"","delineator":"None","illum":"None","offset":"","mountht":"","backing":"Aluminum","width":"","height":"","txtSize":"","numSize":"","comments":" ","twoSided":"Y","attachType":"","attachNum":"","attachLoc":"Main pole","siteObs":"Clear","signShape":"","color2":""}}]
```

and you should add  the following code at line 722 in app/main.js:

```
attributes.objectId = parseInt(attributes.objectId)
```

and you should change the following code at line 262 in index.html

```
<select id="condition" class="form-control" name="condition_" required></select>
```

because your field name is CONDITION_